# QT design studio and QT Widgets application

Tags: qt

I have a QT widget app that I have been making for some time. I want to make GUI for it that looks rich and good. QT Design studio seems a good choice but I can't find resources to be sure that QT design studio GUI can be implemented to QT Widgets app.

Can I integrate UI from QT Design Studio to QT Widgets App (not QML app)?
I found a few links but they are not very clear. Can you help me answer this question, please?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do?  There are lots of ways to use `Qt`, most of which can be integrated with each other in some way. You could start by having a look at the [overview](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/gettingstarted.html).

Comment: You probably want to just use style sheets to give your application a custom style.

Answer (score 0):

No; Qt Design Studio generates QML, whereas [Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtdesigner-manual.html) generates .ui files for widget applications.

Comment: Is there any way to develop rich UIs in widget app?

Comment: What do you mean by "rich"?  You can set custom palette colors on widgets, in Designer.  You can make your own QWidget subclasses if you want to render images or write custom QPainter code.  You can use qss styling, but it has its problems and isn't well-maintained.  Custom QStyle: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtwidgets-widgets-styles-example.html  But if you want animation, it's not a good idea, because QPainter will need to repaint frequently, and that's a lot of work for the CPU.  This is why we have Qt Quick: you want to use the GPU for rendering animations and shader effects.